# ALSA volume change callback not triggering?

Tags: callback, event-handling, alsa, mixer

I have a function that I'm setting as the callback, but events are happening and the funciton is not being called. Is there something else I need to do?

```
// static
int volume_change_callback(snd_mixer_elem_t* elem,
                                              unsigned int mask) {
  // Do stuff
}


snd_mixer_elem_set_callback(element, volume_change_callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use snd_mixer_handle_events() to actually have the callback get called. (http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___mixer.html#gae0cfb6b50ec2493281107b0649f87cb8)

Check out amixer.c (https://fossies.org/dox/alsa-utils-1.0.29/amixer_8c_source.html) for an example of handling events:

```
  while (1) {
      int res;
      res = snd_mixer_wait(handle, -1);
      if (res >= 0) {
          printf("Poll ok: %i\n", res);
          res = snd_mixer_handle_events(handle);
          assert(res >= 0);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Links are dead. If you have updated ones, that would be appreciated. Your answer is good nonetheless: a testament to complete answers with links rather than link-only answers. Thank you!